# Timers in NS2 causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, timer, segmentation-fault, ns2

I am facing a problem while implementing a timer in NS2.I want to implement a timer which on expiry just prints "expired". The code is as follows:

fap.h:

```
class Fap;
class HelloTimer : public TimerHandler
{
   public:
   HelloTimer(Fap* fapAgent) : TimerHandler(){agent = fapAgent;}    
   protected:
   Fap* agent;
   inline virtual void expire(Event* e);        

};

class Fap : public Agent
{
public:
Fap(void);
int filter[ADDRESS_SPACE];
int address;
int netId;
int requestedIp;
bool configured;
nsaddr_t requestor;
nsaddr_t initiator;
HelloTimer helloTimer;
TcpAgent* tcp;
NsObject* ll;
void recv(Packet* p, Handler*);
void sendHello(void);
int command(int, const char* const*);
};
```

fap.cc

```
void HelloTimer:: expire(Event* event)
{
//agent->sendHello();
printf("expired\n");    
}
int Fap::command(int argc, const char* const* argv)
{
Tcl& tcl = Tcl::instance();
if(argc == 2)
{
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "hello") == 0) 
    {
        helloTimer.resched(30); //problem occurs here
                    helloTimer.status(); //no problem with this
                    return (TCL_OK);
    }
}
else if(argc == 3)
{

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "set-ll") == 0)
    {
        NsObject* temp;
        temp = (NsObject*)(TclObject::lookup(argv[2]));
        ll = temp;
        return (TCL_OK);
    }


}
else
{
    printf("invalid number of args");

}
Agent::command(argc,argv);
return(TCL_OK);

}
```

Only relevant parts of the code have been added.Whenever I try to reschedule the timer using resched(), a segmentation fault occurs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is as a result of conflict of class names. Just put prefix on your timer class name.